# How to combine two columns into one formula?

Tags: sharepoint-online, list, modern-experience, calculated-column, calculated-column-formula

I have this formula for column named "Level of Risk":

```
=IF([MultipleFunctional]<6;"LOW";IF([MultipleFunctional]<10;"MEDIUM";IF([MultipleFunctional]<20;"HIGH";"CRITICAL")))
```

It works by "MultipleFunctional", but I need to add column "[Answer]" into this, with this conditions:

```
IF([Answer]="Compliant";"No Risk";IF([Answer]="Not Applicable";"Not Applicable"
```

I tried some but get errors or incorrect work. Is it possible? And what would the formula look like?.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Giving preference to value of `[Answer]` field first, you can use formula like below for your calculated column:

```
=IF([Answer]="Compliant";"No Risk";IF([Answer]="Not Applicable";"Not Applicable",IF([MultipleFunctional]<6;"LOW";IF([MultipleFunctional]<10;"MEDIUM";IF([MultipleFunctional]<20;"HIGH";"CRITICAL")))))
```

Comment: I wrote almost the same code, but the new columns were at the end, so maybe there was a mistake. Anyway thanks for the solution and the new info, thanks, you saved me again.